# Im getting - To prevent an unsafe abort when evaluating the function

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I'm getting:To prevent an unsafe abort when evluating the function 'System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke' all threads were allowed to run. This may have changed the state of the process and any breakpoint encountered have been skipped.

I have read previous solutions in this forum to this solution such as enabling legacy mode to no avail and have disabled -Enable Property Evaluation and other implicit function calls to no avail.

Has anyone found another solution to this problem?  I have VS Enterprise 16.4.4 and the issue persist.